# Refurbished Mac: Can you keep old software after time machine restore?

Tags: time-machine, hardware, time

I've bought a refurbished MacBook Pro (early 2013).

My original one (early 2011) keeps shutting down, so took to repairman who reflowed the logic board (cost 170, didn't work) so payed another150 for him to tinker with it and it came back worse than before, now instead of just turning off it freezes and gives me vertical grey line and repeats the last sound the video I was watching over and ob=ver.

Anyway....... I bought a refurbished one as said, and it has Microsoft 2016. The original Mac has 2010, so I was wondering if there was a way of using time machine to restore (if thats the right word) my old system to the new Mac but keep Microsoft 2016.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a moot point.  Technically, you can migrate the apps and keep existing ones, but the licensing and activation model for Office 2016 will prevent it from running until you sign in with a valid account.  It will work for a period of time (I think 90 days) and after that, it will ask for validation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the 'new' Mac isn't brand new, since new Macs don't come with MS Office pre-installed? Time Machine won't let you do such a selective restore anyway, but in that case the only way to legally keep the copy of 2016 you've acquired is to have its license transferred to you. That will likely involve contacting both the original owner and Microsoft, after which you can install 2016 whenever you like.

See also: https://superuser.com/a/1150086

Comment: He said he bought a refurbished MacBook Pro (Early 2013) in his opening....